# Spring AOP Pointcut with method name starting with get

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to implement a Pointcut for spring AOP. All the methods which are like `getXXXX` should be logged. I tried the following but either they throw exception or does not trigger:

1st try

```
@Pointcut("within(net.services.*.get*)")
private void clServiceLayer() {}

@Pointcut("within(net.services.*.get*(..))")
private void clServiceLayer() {}
```

Need help with the proper expression for point cut.

Comment: Why `within`? You could use `@Pointcut("execution(* net.tds.adm.metasolv.customerlink.services.*.get*(..))")`

Comment: What you suggested has worked. Thank you. I would mark it answered if you put this in the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`within` limits matching to join points within certain types. Instead you should use `execution` *Pointcut Designator* for matching method execution join points:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* net.tds.adm.metasolv.customerlink.services.*.get*(..))")
```

Checkout the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-pointcuts-designators) for more detailed discussion.